# Wordpress block theme remove inline css

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way I can remove the inline CSS generated by Wordpress block theme. I understand this CSS is based on the blocks and would only be generated based on the blocks being used. Is there any way I can remove all this inline CSS and move them to a separate file ?
I have tried using remove_action with the id generated in the style tag along with searching the ID in wp-content folder but I haven't been able to figure out how can I achieve this
[image: Wordpress default theme source code]